# Telerik XML import Picturebox value empty

Tags: c#, xml, telerik, deserialization, telerik-reporting

When I import a, XML of a Telerik Report, which hase an image value in it int he XML, it is empty in my application.

Here's the deserializer:

```
public Telerik.Reporting.Report DeserializeReportXml(string fileName)
{
    var filePath = $"{PATH}{fileName}.xml";

    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true }))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new ReportXmlSerializer();
        return (Telerik.Reporting.Report)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

I Added a debug picture and a XML picture so you can see the value is set in the XML but empty at runtime.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a picture box and the image goes into a control inside the picture box.  You are getting the left/top/ locations correctly.  It looks like the image is a 64 bit string and has to be converted to bin.  Not sure how to do it.

Comment: the XML is generatod trough the Report Designer, and yeah it's a 64Base string. It's weird that the telerik deserializer doesn't say anything about it though ...

Comment: I've worked recently with a RDLC report for a SQL Server.  It was similar that it had two icons the were 64Base Strings and worked well.  The RDLC report is HTML.  You have xml so I don't know if the de-serializer is properly decoding the 64 base string.  Do you have a class object for the picture box? You may need to add a property to decode the string.

Comment: No actually the "Report" has one, and it's from the Telerik.Reporting library. I'm starting to think that it may be related to version issues .